# Absolute path rotativa asp net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rotativa

I'm using rotativa to generate pdf in asp net core 2.0, and it's occurring following error:

**"ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: view"**

I think it happens because rotativa does not accept absolute path to find view. How can i resolve this?

Here is github address of plugin I'm using:
https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore

Comment: you need a controller and action which returns the view, not just the path to the view itself.

Comment: I tried to add full path with controller, but error persists

Comment: See this [issue](https://github.com/webgio/Rotativa.AspNetCore/issues/9) in that repo.

Comment: I added the code above the repository and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set value of property view as below

```
var rpt = new ViewAsPdf();
rpt.ViewName = "Test";
```

After this your issue will be resolved